# Image not taking up container's height

Tags: html, css, image

I have three elements:

.main
  *>* .img-container
   *>>* img

***.main***  has a definite height,
***.img-container***  has a max height equal to the container,
***img***  should take up the containing div's height.

The problem is that the image is not constrained to the container's height,
as shown in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qtgye/jozyz1uo/).

Please note that the image has to be limited to the container's height, not only making it vertically middle.

Thanks for your help.

Here is the current scss:

```
.main {
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #eee;

    .img-container {
        background-color: #ddd;
        max-height: 100%;
        width: 80%; /* just to show the main container */

        img {
            height: 100%;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you put this in a fiddle along with html, so we can dry run

Comment: It already has a fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Use height in `.main .img-container` class

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jozyz1uo/1/)**

```
.main .img-container {
    background-color: #ddd;
    /*max-height: 100%;*/
    height: 100%;
    width: 80%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Worked for me.
I have changed the max-height of image-container and height of img.

```
.main {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #eee;

  .img-container {
    background-color: #ddd;
    max-height: inherit;
    width: 80%; /* just to show the main container */

    img {
        height: inherit;
    }
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

may be you want this

```
.main {
height: 200px;
background-color: #eee;
text-align:center;

.img-container {
    background-color: #ddd;
   height: 100%;
    width: 80%; /* just to show the main container */



    img {
        height: 100%;
    }
    }
}
```

i have replaced max-height with height and added text-align to center in main container. if you don't need image at center then remove text-align:center

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.It's working for me

```
.main {
height: 200px;
background-color: #eee;

.img-container {
    background-color: #ddd;
    height: 100%;
   width: 80%;

    img {
        height: 100%;
    }
   }
 }
```